# Log all failed attempts in testcafe quarantine mode?

Tags: e2e-testing, testcafe, ui-testing

I have quarantine mode enabled in my testcafe configuration.

```
"ci-e2e": {
    "browsers": [
        "chrome:headless"
    ],
    "debugOnFail": false,
    "src": "./tests/e2e/*.test.ts",
    "concurrency": 1,
    "quarantineMode": true,
    "reporters": [
        {
            "name": "nunit3",
            "output": "results/e2e/testResults.xml"
        },
        {
            "name": "spec"
        }
    ],
    "screenshots": {
        "takeOnFails": true,
        "path": "results/ui/screenshots",
        "pathPattern": "${DATE}_${TIME}/${FIXTURE}/${TEST}/Screenshot-${QUARANTINE_ATTEMPT}.png"
    },
    "video": {
        "path": "results/ui/video",
        "failedOnly": true,
        "pathPattern": "${DATE}_${TIME}/${FIXTURE}/${TEST}/Video-${QUARANTINE_ATTEMPT}"
    }
},
```

Now when some attempt fails I have entry in log (nunit xml logfile) with information about failed runs and only one stack-trace. I have screenshot for each failed run.

```
<failure>
    <message>
        <![CDATA[ ❌ AssertionError: ... Run 1: Failed Run 2: Failed Run 3: Failed ]]>
    </message>
    <stack-trace>
        here we have stack-trace for only one failed run
    </stack-trace>
</failure>
```

I want to have log entry with stack-trace for each failed run for each failed test. Is it possible to configure testcafe this way? If not what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the config file. The name of the option for reporters should be `reporter`, but it is `reporterS`. It means that Testcafe doesn't use these reporters at all and maybe now you just see an outdated file with results.